# mySQL select lowest level categories by keyword

Tags: mysql

I have the following table which stores all product category data distinguished by "level":

**all_categories**

```
record_id   title                     level    parent_category_id   parent_id
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
7           Cars, Bikes & Boats       0        NULL                 NULL
5687        Car parts & accessories   1        7                    7
5691        Cars                      1        7                    7
```

**parent_id** is the given category's immediate parent

**parent_category_id** is the given category's top level parent

I have the following query, which executes when the user enters a keyword, e.g. "car"

```
SELECT distinct t1.record_id, t1.title, t1.level, t1.keywords 
FROM all_categories t1 
LEFT JOIN all_categories t2
  ON t1.record_id = t2.parent_id
WHERE t1.title LIKE ('%car%') or t1.keywords LIKE ('%car%')
```

This returns the following category data:

```
record_id   title                     level 
-------------------------------------------
7           Cars, Bikes & Boats       0        
5687        Car parts & accessories   1      
5691        Cars                      1
```

However, I only want to return categories at the lowest "level". So if "car" was entered as keyword, I only want to return record_id = 5691 or 5687, not any of the parents of this record (record_id = 7 is its parent).

This shows a simple example with only two levels, but there could be any number of parent levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by just checking that any entries that match the keyword have no children (assuming that a child's `parent_id` refers to `record_id` of the parent)

```
SELECT  t1.record_id, t1.title, t1.level
FROM all_categories t1 
WHERE (t1.title LIKE '%car%' or t1.keywords LIKE '%car%') AND
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM all_categories t2 
               WHERE t2.parent_id = t1.record_id)
```

Output (from your sample data):

```
record_id   title                       level
5687        "Car parts & accessories"   1
5691        "Cars"                      1
```

Comment: Thanks for this Nick, but the lowest level for a particular category might not be level 3. It depends on how many levels the particular supercategory has.

Comment: This code is not dependent on the number of levels being 3 it just checks against the maximum number of levels whatever that might be. If it doesn't work for your data can you post some data that shows that?

Comment: There are different levels of depth depending on the supercategory, i.e. some top level categories might have three child levels, while others might only have one. So, if the code checks for the maximum number of levels the database currently has as a whole (which it seems to), it might find that level 3 is the deepest it currently goes, but there will still be some categories that only go one level deep. So, the code will miss anything that isn't three levels deep. I'll post some data shortly.

Comment: Ok I think I get what you're saying. I'll wait to see your sample data but I suspect what you're trying to achieve might be quite tricky.

Comment: Yeah, basically I just want to get data that doesn't have any children.

Comment: I've modified my query based on your last comment - this one will find matching entries which have no children.

Comment: Thanks Nick, you seem to have nailed it!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
SELECT record_id, title, LEVEL
FROM all_categories 
WHERE (title LIKE '%car%') AND
      LEVEL = (SELECT MIN(t1.level)
FROM all_categories t1 JOIN all_categories t2 ON t1.record_id = t2.record_id
WHERE t1.record_id != t1.parent_category_id AND t1.record_id != t1.parent_id
AND t1.title LIKE '%car%')
```